# Spring-xd doesn't write stream from Twitter on HDFS

Tags: spring, hadoop, twitter, spring-xd

I'm working in my final thesis and I have a problem with Spring-xd:

I run from my xd-shell:

> stream create --name cyrustweets --definition "twitterstream
>   --track='mileycyrus, miley cyrus' | log" --deploy

And it works. My xd-singlenode show me the tweets.

But when I try write on HDFS:

> stream create --name cyrustweets --definition "twitterstream
>   --track='mileycyrus, miley cyrus' | **hdfs**" --deploy

The xd-singlenode show me the next:

> 08:28:05,763 1.0.3.RELEASE  WARN twitterSource-1-1
>   twitter.TwitterStreamChannelAdapter - Exception while reading stream.
>   org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: failed to
>   write Message payload to HDFS.

Any help? I followed this tutorial: 
http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/using-spring-xd-to-stream-tweets-to-hadoop-for-sentiment-analysis/

Thanks so much

Comment: Can you show the complete stack trace from the log? Post it to someplace else (e.g. a gist) if it's too big for here.

Comment: Complete log is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ac62851d96730a828c68

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is from source side. Twitter API has some restrictions on streaming time and typically it is determined by your IP address. You will not be able to replicate 100 MB tweets in hardly 30 minutes. From my experience you have to steam them daily over a period of weeks's time to get significant log files.

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Conexión rehusada

This means the HDFS port and/or host name is incorrect (`Connection Refused` in English).

If you are using newer versions of Spring-XD, the hadoop connection properties are configured in `servers.yml`, with these defaults:

```
# Hadoop properties 
  hadoop:
    fsUri: hdfs://localhost:8020
    resourceManagerHost: localhost
    resourceManagerPort: 8032
```

Comment: What should I change in these defaults settings?
Just localhost for the IP address of my virtual machine?
Thanks

Comment: The the host and port where you have the namenode running. I am not familiar with the Hortonworks sandbox but their tutorial says:  "... You can find the IP Address of the Sandbox as it loads:"

Comment: There are some instructions for using the HDP Sandbox on the XD wiki -- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/wiki/Using-Hadoop-VMs-with-Spring-XD#hortonworks-sandbox